# ModuleNotFoundError when trying to install torch_sparse in virtual environment

Tags: pytorch, python-venv

I am fairly new to torch and also to usage of virtual environments, hence the question might be dumb but none of the proposed solutions found online worked for me.

I am trying to replicate a paper using my university's linux server. Such paper requires, among other things, `torch==1.7.1` and `torch_sparse==0.6.7`. I created a venv in the code directory and pip installed all required packages in the venv. No problem when installing `torch==1.7.1`, but when I run `pip install torch-sparse==0.6.7` I get the following error

```
Collecting torch-sparse==0.6.7
  Using cached torch_sparse-0.6.7.tar.gz (34 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [17 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
```

[...]

```
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

NOTE: I have no idea why, but previously I was able to correctly install `torch_sparse==0.6.7`, but I encountered another problem: when running the main script which imports all packages I had the following error:

```
Detected that PyTorch and torch_sparse were compiled with different CUDA versions. PyTorch has CUDA version 10.2 and torch_sparse has CUDA version 11.4. Please reinstall the torch_sparse that matches your PyTorch install.
```

In trying to solve this second issue (uninstalling torch_sparse and trying out different solutions found online) I somehow made it impossible to download torch_sparse in the first place :_)